# How do I solve "Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less CSS, where Autoprefixer is no longer needed for your stylesheet."?

Tags: javascript, css, next.js, autoprefixer

In my Next.JS app I import my stylesheet in `_app.js` like this:

```
import '../public/css/Index.css';
```

`Index.css` contains this:

```
.index-container {
    margin: 20px auto 0;
}
```

How do I solve the error message:

> ./src/public/css/Index.css
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/postcss-loader??__nextjs_postcss!./src/public/css/Index.css)
> Warning
>
> Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less
> CSS, where Autoprefixer is no longer needed for your stylesheet.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Your issue can be solved `package.json` by applying code below:

```
 "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.3%",
      "not ie 11",
      "not dead", 
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      ">0.3%",
      "not ie 11",
      "not dead", 
      "not op_mini all"
    ]
  }
```

After you have made these changes restart your server. you will no longer get this warning.

Comment: An explanation to why this fixes the issue would help. :)

Answer (score 13):

I had to change both production and dev items as follows and this worked.

```
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.3%",
    "not ie 11",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
"development": [
    ">0.3%",
    "not ie 11",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
},
```

Comment: This fixed for me... should others note: I encountered this issue after npm audit fix, my package.json already looked like the accepted answer, changing to this solved my issue. What a horrendous warning.

Answer (score 9):

`npx browserslist --update-db` worked for me

Comment: For Angular (v11 for me), this command updated my package-lock.json. Just after re run my application, libraries was compiled and application ran without error. 
see this link and take in account readme.md for more explanations :
https://github.com/browserslist/update-db

Answer (score 5):

This was an issue due to some incompatibility between `browserslist` and the bundled version of `postcss-preset-env` with `v9.4.4`.

Updating to `v9.5.0` should solve it.