# create-react-app giving warning about golden age of prefix-less CSS, how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

*Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less CSS, where Autoprefixer is no longer needed for your stylesheet.*

Other solution talk about updating the docs directly but that didn't work, plus this is a create-react-app, is there a way for that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I solve "Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less CSS, where Autoprefixer is no longer needed for your stylesheet."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62883240/how-do-i-solve-greetings-time-traveller-we-are-in-the-golden-age-of-prefix-le)

Answer (score 4):

Update the `react-scripts` used by `create-react-app` script for *that* project with

```
npm install react-scripts@latest
```

For NEW applications this is not a problem as

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

will get the *latest* react-scripts version

So basically this is only a problem for older create-react-app version (i.e. all apps as they age).