# remove autoprefixer warning in react 17.0.2

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sass

I'm currently using **React 17.0.2** (in `create-react-app` environment) and **SCSS**, and all of a sudden I'm constantly receiving the following warning from **React**:

> Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less CSS, where Autoprefixer is no longer needed for your stylesheet.

I haven't updated anything (at least to my knowledge), and the Sass Compiler that I'm using has autoprefixes disabled.

I've tried following all of the answers on this thread: [How do I solve "Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less CSS, where Autoprefixer is no longer needed for your stylesheet."?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62883240/6425936)
And then running `npm update --save` to no avail.

The warning is constantly obfuscating important messages and errors, and is quite a pain to deal with, so all help is appreciated.

Comment: which code do you use for creating a new project? npm create-react-app or npx create-react-app

Comment: This should be a comment. But, I used `npx`.

Comment: I make a new project with npx 
but we don't have a warning

please test this code

`npm audit fix`
or
`yarn audit fix`

Answer (score 1):

Check your built react folder and confirm the CSS file to see if there're vendor prefixes? If so, try something like this:

`.b { /* autoprefixer: off */ transition: 1s;  }`.

See [autoprefixer comment](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#control-comments)