# Esseor after installing Axios in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

After installing Axios via `npm axios install`, when I try to run my script via `npm run start` I am getting the error below

```
[0] Compiled with warnings.
[0]
[0] ./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./n
ode_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
[0] Warning
[0]
[0] Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less CSS, wher
e Autoprefixer is no longer needed for your stylesheet.
[0]
[0] ./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./nod
e_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/App.css)
[0] Warning
[0]
[0] Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less CSS, wher
e Autoprefixer is no longer needed for your stylesheet.
[0]
[0] ./node_modules/monday-ui-react-core/dist/main.css (./node_modules/css-loader
/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node
_modules/monday-ui-react-core/dist/main.css)
[0] Warning
[0]
[0] Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less CSS, wher
e Autoprefixer is no longer needed for your stylesheet.
[0]
[0] Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
[0] To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was solved by applying the code at **production and dev items** within **package.json** file

```
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.3%",
    "not ie 11",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
"development": [
    ">0.3%",
    "not ie 11",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
},
```

see solution [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62883240/how-do-i-solve-greetings-time-traveller-we-are-in-the-golden-age-of-prefix-le)