# How to remove "autoprefixer: Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less CSS, .." warning in Angular 11?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, autoprefixer

I am using Angular version 11 and I see this warning:

Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Warning

"autoprefixer: Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less CSS, where Autoprefixer is no longer needed for your stylesheet."

Can anyone please tell how to remove it, it is really annoying.

Comment: run this command in terminal **npm uninstall Autoprefixer** or remove Autoprefixer from package.json and run **npm install**

Comment: @mmh4all I don't see any autoprefixer in my package.json file.

Comment: then what you want to remove if you don't have it?

Comment: Edited the question above. I want to remove the autoprefixer: warning caused by: "Module Warning (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):" from the angular cli.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I solve "Greetings, time traveller. We are in the golden age of prefix-less CSS, where Autoprefixer is no longer needed for your stylesheet."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62883240/how-do-i-solve-greetings-time-traveller-we-are-in-the-golden-age-of-prefix-le)

Comment: I pasted the browserlist configuration in package.json but thereafter my local server was not starting. I was then getting: "An unhandled exception occurred: " message.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the node_modules and the package-lock.json and then run:
npm install
Now restart the local server: ng serve
The 'autoprefixer' warnings were not shown now.